# JPA Native Query (SQL View)

Tags: java, jpa-2.0

I have two Entities `Customer` and `Account`.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="customer")
public class Customer
{
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private Long accountId;
    private String accountType;
    private String accountName;

    ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name="account")
public class Account
{
    private Long id;
    private String accountName;
    private String accountType;
    ...
}
```

I have an SQL query:

```
select 
    a.id as account_id, 
    a.account_name, 
    a.account_type, 
    d.id, 
    d.name
from account a, 
     customer d`
where d.account_id = a.id
```

**Assumption**

1. `account` and `customer` tables are created in the database during application startup.
2. `accountType` and `accountName` fields of Customer entity should not be created in the database. That is, only `id` and `name` columns will be created in the customer database table.

**Question**

How do I run the above SQL query and return a `Customer` Entity with the `accountType` and `accountName` properties populated with the SQL query's account_name and account_type values.

Comment: Can you go for hibernate    ?

Comment: I don't really get your question. What are these 'assumptions'? This is how you would like this code to work? You don't want to persist the `accountType` and `accountName` properties of Customer entity? (`@Transient`?)  Do you want these properties to be a part of composite PK? What is the relationship between Customer and Account? You SQL query will return a Cartesian product in this form (there is no correlation between the entities)...

Comment: accountType and accountName are not composite Pk, i am using id as the primary key. I have updated the post. Like you said, the accountType and accountName properties of Customer entity are @Transient. Customer Entity has a reference to Account entity. i want to retrieve a Customer Entity from the database that does not contain Account entity but contain accountType and accountName of the Account record it is referencing in the database. If you have a better way of getting these two properties, please share it. thanks

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are really trying to do two distinct things at once.  Retrieve the two objects from the database, that is really what a select is for right?  So when JPA finishes a select, you would expect your entities to have the information currently stored in the database.

So why not just do a SELECT then an UPDATE?

Also, is there a business reason to have the information duplicated?  From a design perspective, should the customer have an Account object associated with it rather than duplicating the account type and number?

Comment: Customer entity references Account Entity in the Database. I am not doing an update. i want to retrieve a Customer Entity from the database that does not contain Account entity but contains accountType and accountName of the Account record it is referencing in the database. If you have a better way of getting these two properties, please share it. thanks